# DynamoDB query BETWEEN of Global Secondary Index not working (ObjectiveC)

Tags: ios, amazon-dynamodb

My DynamoDB Query is returning "Query key condition not supported".

```
NSMutableDictionary * conditions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

DynamoDBCondition * googleConditionLat = [[DynamoDBCondition alloc] init];
googleConditionLat.comparisonOperator = @"BETWEEN";
DynamoDBAttributeValue * googleIDAttributeLat1 = [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithN:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude - 0.0005]];
[googleConditionLat addAttributeValueList:googleIDAttributeLat1];
DynamoDBAttributeValue * googleIDAttributeLat2 = [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithN:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude + 0.0005]];
[googleConditionLat addAttributeValueList:googleIDAttributeLat2];
[conditions setObject:googleConditionLat forKey:kLatitudeKey];

#if 1
DynamoDBCondition * googleConditionLong = [[DynamoDBCondition alloc] init];
googleConditionLong.comparisonOperator = @"BETWEEN";
DynamoDBAttributeValue * googleIDAttributeLong1 = [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithN:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude - 0.0005]];
[googleConditionLong addAttributeValueList:googleIDAttributeLong1];
DynamoDBAttributeValue * googleIDAttributeLong2 = [[DynamoDBAttributeValue alloc] initWithN:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude + 0.0005]];
[googleConditionLong addAttributeValueList:googleIDAttributeLong2];
[conditions setObject:googleConditionLong forKey:kLongitudeKey];
#endif

NSMutableDictionary *queryStartKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];;
do
{
    DynamoDBQueryRequest *queryRequest = [[DynamoDBQueryRequest alloc] init];
    queryRequest.tableName = PLACE_TABLE_NAME;
    queryRequest.exclusiveStartKey = queryStartKey;
    queryRequest.keyConditions = conditions;
    queryRequest.consistentRead = false;
    queryRequest.indexName = @"lat-long-global-index";

    @try
    {
        DynamoDBQueryResponse *queryResponse = [[AmazonClientManager ddb] query:queryRequest];
```

My global secondary index is:

```
Index Name: lat-long-global-index Hash Key:lat (Number) Range Key:long (Number)
```

I have a very similar query on a GSI to the same table with one string hash key using "EQ" which works fine.

Any thoughts appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, you can't use BETWEEN on HASH

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditions):

> For a query on an index, you can only have conditions on the index key
>   attributes. **You must specify the index hash attribute name and value
>   as an EQ condition**. You can optionally specify a second condition,
>   referring to the index key range attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Was wondering if that was the cause. Will have to look into the Geo DynamoDB code - looks like that may help

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by trying the query on the AWS console. It looks like you cant check for a range of values on the first key - it is a hash key same as the primary hash key.

A table redesign required...

Comment: This one solved my case. I need price based filters. Users can search the products within a price range.